# User Agent String for Eclipse

Tags: http, eclipse, user-agent

Is it possible to change the User Agent String for requests made by Eclipse?

After some experiments with curl I believe that certain User Agents are favoured by our company proxy (they get access to more sites).

Answer (score 0):

One can use Fiddler to change the User Agent for all outgoing http requests. This is not completely satisfactory, but a usable workaround.